# What is the best / latest software to convert DVD recorder disc to YouTube?

Tags: dvd, youtube, handbrake, virtualdub

I recorded some Wii gameplay to a DVD-R using a DVD recorder, and tried using Handbrake to convert it to YouTube compatible format.

Basically, it needs resizing to 16:9, and selecting 00:03 to 3:10 of the video (out of the 7 minutes).

It seems Handbrake can't do it for 480p... and if using AutoGK and then VirtualDub to resize and do video time selection, it feels so old school (autogk not updated since 2005)...  Windows Movie Maker seems like 15fps video quality...  DivX Converter will make the video 816 x 456, just a little bit not enough for YouTube to show it as 480p.

Is there a way to do it nicely?

---

Details if using Handbrake:

I can't find a way to convert a DVD recorded video which is 720 x 480 (Wii Gameplay in 16 : 9 ratio) into 852 x 480... It seems that the only possible resize is to shrink but not to expand?

It is fine to make it 720 x 406... except YouTube won't be able to show it as 480p... If it can be made 852 x 480, then YouTube can at least show it as 480p (besides 360p and 240p)...

Right now my way of doing it is to using AutoGK, and it can only make it 720 x 540, and then I will use VirtualDub to resize it 852 x 480 and select the video portion I want.  But the vertical height 480 is converted to 544 first, and then back to 480, so there probably is some quality loss there.

is there any way to do it? thanks.

Comment: I would of thought Handbrake could do this in its sleep! I don't know what is wrong here and I can not test due to not having a similar setup to test, but I would ask on their forums/IRC or similar....

Answer (score 0):

[VirtualDub 720p HD settings for YouTube! [Good quality, small file size]](http://www.donsalva.com/virtualdub-720p-hd-settings-youtube/)

Comment: isn't this for video games playing on the PC?  What if it is a Wii game... can you capture it using FRAPS?

Comment: Doesn't matter what it's for. VirtualDub is like Handbrake, what kind of video you're transcoding is up to you. Whether it be a dvd recorded footage or some gameplay footage.